# emulator: ERROR: Can't get kernel version from the kernel image file

Tags: android-emulator, android-12, aosp

I want to start the emulator for the custom AOSP 12L build for arm64 using emulatorcommand. The AOSP source was downloaded from Sony's open device project for Xperia devices.

The command that I ran is :

> $ emulator64-x86 -sysdir
> /home/anerudh/android/out/target/product/generic_arm64/ -system
> /home/anerudh/android/out/target/product/generic_arm64/system.img
> -ramdisk /home/anerudh/android/out/target/product/generic_arm64/ramdisk.img
> -data /home/anerudh/android/out/target/product/generic_arm64/userdata-qemu.img
> -kernel /home/anerudh/android/out/target/product/generic_arm64/kernel-5.4
> -sdcard /home/anerudh/android/out/target/product/generic_arm64/sdcard.img

I get the following error and do not know where to change the 'Linux version' in the kernel image

```
emulator : ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image <file_path>
```

How do I solve this issue and start the emulator?

Comment: I hope this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10101698/10147641) may help you.